# How to add a profile picture in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I want the user to have the option of uploading his picture online. I want to add a new tab in 'My account' menu with a button to add, delete his profile picture.

Comment: Did you have a solution ? Please share it

Comment: I did not implement it